Installing Verilator on an Apple M3 Mac?
I have been trying to install Verilator on an Apple Silicon Mac for some time and keep facing issues. Homebrew allows normal installation but its behaviour during operation is rather weird. It can run its own demo program but when I try to run the very simple demo program in the tutorial I keep getting an error on line 10, which says that the Verilog file is invalid because of "variable inlining"
When I follow the instructions of the below tutorial one of the errors I get is a rather weird configure: error: the g++ -std=gnu++11 compiler appears to not support C++11. which I haven't been able to fix.
Verilog Development on Apple Silicon Macs (M1/M2/M3) - A Step-by-Step Guide to Setting up Verilator, SystemC and GTKWave on macOS
Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?
